# how to aovoid situation in which gridView is covering my uilabel now:iphone

Tags: iphone, gmgridview

What I am having right now is

```
View :
    1.UILabel :  show a text 
    2.A GMGridView : show a grid of views
```

The codes are

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        gridViewHolder.itemSpacing      =   SPACING;
        gridViewHolder.dataSource       =   self;
        gridViewHolder.actionDelegate   =   self;
    }
#pragma mark - GMGridViewDataSource
- (CGSize)GMGridView:(GMGridView *)gridView sizeForItemsInInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    return CGSizeMake(WIDTH, HEIGT);     
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInGMGridView:(GMGridView *)gridView {
    return [needs count];
}
- (GMGridViewCell *)GMGridView:(GMGridView *)gridView cellForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    cell                =   [gridView dequeueReusableCell];
    CGSize size         =   [self GMGridView:gridViewHolder sizeForItemsInInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];

    if (!cell)
        cell            =   [[GMGridViewCell alloc] init];  

    UIView      *innerView                  =   [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(COOR_X, COOR_Y, size.width, size.height)];
    innerView.backgroundColor               =   [UIColor grayColor];

    cell.contentView                        =   innerView;
    return cell;
}
```

[image]

So now I can successfully to display a bunch of views in gridview. However, the content of the grid view will cover the label when I am scrolling the grid view. Below is the picture so that you can see my situation now
[image]

How can avoid this situation so that whenever I scroll up my gridview, its contents wont be overlapped with my uilabel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
gridview.clipsToBounds=TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the gridview below the label using insertSubview on the view.

[self.view insertSubview:gmGridView atIndex:0];